# Is there any difference between the Dell Inspiron 5447 and the Dell Inspiron 5457 cooler?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling

I have a Dell Inspiron 5457 notebook and its cooler started to make a loud noise. I have tried to clean the fan, but the noise continued the same.

As I didn't manage to fix the cooler I will have to replace it, so I would like to know if there is any difference between the Dell Inspiron 5457 cooler and the Dell Inspiron 5447 cooler.

Could anyone tell me if there is any difference between both?

Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes dell uses different part numbers even in the SAME model of computer. If you want to know you are getting the same part, get the part number off of the actual part and order it by part number. You can’t be sure you’re getting the same part simply by referencing the model number of the laptop. Additionally, you may be able to find the part number y going to dell support and entering your service tag, then looking at your system configuration to see what is in it. Not sure if a heatsink / fan will show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a driver issue with the Bios update. Check the Dell website for updates. I have the 5579 and started this. Now quiet. Also in properties turn off the Bluetooth to where it shows in the checkbox for your system to turn it on/off. No issues after this all was addressed. Very quiet now. It's not your fan (cooler), it's updates for the most part. Hope this helps.